# Variable not found error

Tags: php, html, syntax

Hey, can anyone notice any errors in this code:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if(isSet($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
  $lastmsg = $_POST['lastmsg'];
  $lastmsg = mysql_real_escape_string($lastmsg);
  $result  = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                            FROM updates 
                           WHERE update_time < '$lastmsg' 
                        ORDER BY msg_id DESC
                           LIMIT 9");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $msg_id  = $row['update_time'];
    $message = $row['item_content'];
  ?>
   <li>
     <?php echo $message; ?>
   </li>
  <?php
  }
  ?>

  //More Button here $msg_id values is a last message id value.
  <div id="more<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="morebox">
  <a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="more">more</a>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: msg_id in C:\wamp\www\stream_scripts\draft2\ajax_more.php on line 20 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0012373824{main}( )..\ajax_more.php:0 " class="morebox"> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: msg_id in C:\wamp\www\stream_scripts\draft2\ajax_more.php on line 21 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0012373824{main}( )..\ajax_more.php:0 " class="more">more
```

Anyone can see anything wrong please comment. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume that $result always return something as $msg_id is being defined inside the *while* loop. You can check if msg_id has been set by inserting a condition before you try to grab your variable's value such as:

```
<?
if (isset($msg_id)) {
 //More Button here $msg_id values is a last message id value.?>
 <div id="more<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="morebox">
 <a href="#" id="<?php echo $msg_id; ?>" class="more">more</a>
}
```

Also, the following lines don't look right:

```
</li>
<?php
}
?>
* Missing <? here *
//More Button here $msg_id values is a last message id value.
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is if this while loop doesn't run, `$msg_id` will never get set. To remedy this, set `$msg_id` to a default value outside of the loop (i.e. "") or check it's existance when you want to access it

An example might be

```
$msg_id = "";
while(/* conditions */){
  //body
}
```

or

```
   while(){
     $msg_id = "something";
   }

   if(isset($msg_id)){
     // access it
   }
```

Comment: -1 : Do you mean the following code should give a notice? Because it is not. `<?php
$a = false;
while ($a =!$a)
{
  $b = 42;
}
var_dump($b);`

Answer (score 1):

$msg_id is scoped in the while loop. You have to declare it outside the scope.

Demonstration of the problem [here](http://codepad.org/CzaOU3v9).

Solution:

Add this before the while loop:

```
$msg_id = '';
$message = '';
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

On the second occurence of `$msg_id`, you're assuming it has already been defined, but if the while loop doesn't loop at all, it won't.

Answer (score -1):

Yep. If while cycle doesn't role $msg_id wouldn't be defined. It's not an error, it's just a notice. Use error_reporting function if you don't need this message

> error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ) ;

Just place it in the beginning of the script

Comment: I just answered the question, there is no error. For any suggestions one need to know the task, aha. Actually $msg_id=""; in this case makes same job as turning E_NOTICE off

Comment: The downvote button is label "This answer is not usefutl", not "This answer has errors". Plus this turns off all notices in the script so no, it does not make the same job as `$msg_id = ''`, it does much worse.